# Calendar library for Xamarin-Forms

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to work on an application which has features on time-management, appointments etc. 
So basically I thought using a calendar library.

I would like to use a built-in app calendar which I would use, and not just access the calendar which is in my phone. 
I tried looking on a few libraries and plug-ins, for example :

1. https://github.com/TheAlmightyBob/Calendars/ - Cross-platform plugin for querying and modifying device calendars( NO, i don't want to modify device calendars, I want my own calendar inside the app??)
2. https://devhub.io/repos/jamesmontemagno-Calendars  - Cross-platform plugin for querying and modifying device calendars( NO, i don't want to modify device calendars, I want my own calendar inside the app??)
3. https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls/xamarin-calendar (very very expensive)

I also saw quite a few other apps which are the same, modifying device calendars.

So basically what my question is, **do you guys know any calendar libraries which I can use on my project?**
***Do all calendar libraries just modifye only the exsisting calendar found on the phone?*** Because the user just needs to make an appointment on the app, there is no need to show that appointment on his phone calendar...

**Should I just create the whole infrastucture in the back-end and not use the calendar at all on the user interface?**

Please feel free to suggest me anything. Thank you a lot in advance guys. :)

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is **off-topic** for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason these libraries tend to connect to the device's calendar is because most users just want one place to look at their appointments, and have that synced across their devices via their existing google/apple/MS accounts.

That said, there are certainly a lot of apps/systems that maintain a separate schedule and calendar, usually because they have requirements that go beyond what the built-in calendar can do.

If you're not going to use the device calendar, you need two different pieces, and it seems you've only looked at the device-side of things so far:

1. You need a calendar/scheduling 'engine' that would either be hosted in the app or on a backend, and is completely separate from the any front-end layer. I'd strongly suggest the server-based approach, which allows users to have multiple devices connected and all their data backed up. There will be many solutions for this varying in cost and complexity. These would have nothing to do with mobile or xamarin. You'd want to research these in the same way as if you'd be building a website that requires calendar/scheduling. This is one of those things that has been built many, many times and there are likely tons of options. There's probably a third-party solution that would suit your needs somewhere, whether it's just a library you integrate/customise, or a SaS you connect to.
2. The front-end components that run on the device and use the data coming from the backend engine. This is where components like the one from Syncfusion will likely be very helpful. Syncfusion is only expensive if you're a fairly large company, otherwise, you should look at their community license https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Comment: Please try not to answer off-topic questions.

Comment: @Enigmativity And Why not? It's not like I'm asking for someone to do my job.. just asking which would be the best way to do a simple task... this is whta this site is about or not?? Help each others and share knowledge.

Comment: @ben-reierson Thank you very much. I really appreciate it. Yes I thought I might use back-end to develop this part, just  thought of asking since two minds is better than one. I also sent syncfusion.com an email to ask for the free license. Thank you :)

Comment: @Pavel - Well, if what you mean by "Help each others and share knowledge" is answer people's questions, then no, not directly. This site is about creating a corpus of good quality questions and good quality answers for those questions. It's about helping the third-party that sees the answers and the questions in the future. Answering off-topic questions reduces the quality of the site.

Comment: @Pavel - You'll find that as you earn rep on this site you get increasingly greater powers to help improve the quality of the questions and answers. It becomes the community's job to set the community's standards.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm 100% positive that tomorrow, or after tomorrow someone will come here with the same questions and same querys. In that case this question will be extremely helpful for those guys too. Why is this not a good quality question? Cause I'm surer as hell it's a good quality answer I received. 
Not saying anything, I'm just trying to uinderstand what you guys think.  
'It's about helping the third-party that sees the answers and the questions in the future.'..? Are you sure? Cause I don't think this was the purpose of the site when it was first created.

Comment: @Pavel - Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ? They will tell you what the official position is for this site.

Comment: @Pavel - Also, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292175/what-is-the-purpose-of-stack-overflow